# How to create new hook for product page using my own module in Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop

I need to list the related product items for selected products. I have new for list the related products.

I have following hook to display the related products.

```
 public function hookDisplayProductTabContent($params) {
   $related_items = Product::getRelatedProducts((int) $this->context->language->id, 0, (int)Configuration::get('NEW_PRODUCTS_NBR'),(int) $id_product);
 return $this->display(__FILE__, 'views/frontend/relateditems.tpl');
}
```

ProductTabContent not display the related products. How can I achieve this. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the $related_items variable to Smarty.

```
$this->smarty->assign('related_items', $related_items);
```